# Mean Value Theorem related problem

Tags: analysis

Let $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x \in I$, where $I$ is an interval $\subseteq$ R. Also, let $f(c) = g(c)$ for some $c \in I$ but not an endpoint.
Prove that $f'(c) = g'(c)$ (assume differentiablity)

I have tried the Mean Value Theorem, let I = [a,b]. So for $f'(c) = g'(c)$ I will need to prove that $f(a) - f(b) = g(a) - g(b)$, but I am stuck at this. I have also tried the definition of derivative but I am still unable to go ahead.

Please give me some hints on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take the function $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$
we see that $h(x) \ge 0 = h(c)$ for all $x \in I$

So $c$ is a point of local minimum for $h$ is in the interval $I$.

Since $c$ is internal point to $I$, and $h$ is differentiable at $c$
(and that's so because both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $c$),
it follows that $h'(c) = 0$ (there is a very basic theorem stating this).

[Fermat's theorem (stationary points)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points))

This theorem is more basic than the mean value theorem (MVT),
meaning it's usually proven before the MVT is proven (in real analysis courses).

So now we have $0 = h'(c) = f'(c) - g'(c)$

So it follows that $f'(c) = g'(c)$

So all in all, your problem is just a simple exercise of this theorem.
I don't think the problem is MVT related.

If you're interested in a proof, it's very simple

[Proof of Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Proof_2:_Extremum_implies_derivative_vanishes)

Comment: Hi, I have a question: can we extend this proof to the case when c is at the boundary (let's say the left one), can we prove that $f'(c) \leq g'(c)$

Comment: @sucksatmath Yes, to prove this inequality won't be a problem, it follows trivially by taking a limit. But if it's on the boundary then of course we just have right/left derivative there (at point c). Regarding the equality - I am not sure right now.

Comment: The looser restriction with $c$ at the left boundary corresponds to the case in my answer with $x > c$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another view, though @peter.petrov's excellent answer is better IMO and points towards a very useful generalization.

Let's look at the ratio $\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$ for points near $c$.

By hypothesis for all $x$ in the interval
$$f(x) - f(c) \leq g(x) - f(c) = g(x) - g(c)$$

for $x > c$ then, we have
$$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \leq \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}$$

$$\lim_{x \to c+} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}\leq \lim_{x \to c+} \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}$$
or
$$f'(c) \leq g'(c)$$
However, for $x$ approaching $c$ from the left, the denominator $(x-c)$ is negative, so the inequality will be flipped, leaving us with

$$f'(c) \geq g'(c)$$

Taking these two statements together we have
$$f'(c) \leq g'(c) \leq f'(c)$$
Therefore, $f'(c) = g'(c)$.